# Which one is better if we compare Realm and GreenDAO Local Storage Databases for Android? What is reason that making one of them Slower?

Tags: performance, orm, realm, greendao, nosql

I am developing an android App and want to use Database for Local Storage.I have Searched on internet and found some comparisons between Local Storage Databases. But I have to Choose between Realm and GreenDAO. So please suggest me for which one to use.

Comment: Realm is not an ORM, because Realm is not a relational database.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is a comparison of NoSQL(Realm) and ORM(GreenDAO).

**NoSQL is better option if you need to handle large dataset and your queries do not need so many joins.** Example:- If you need to fetch data from five tables, realm will give you options to filter data from two tables (one join at a time) then apply next join condition and so on. ORM has an advantage on joins as a Relational Database.

[NoSQL database is used by Facebook, Google and LinkedIn:-](http://blog.outsourcing-partners.com/2012/10/why-nosql-database-is-used-by-facebook-google-and-linkedin-applications/)

Comment: Okay.Then what is reason that making is making one of them slower?

Comment: No single option is faster for all scenarios. 
It depends. Doing SELECT A FROM T WHERE A='B', providing that A is indexed, is much faster than full table scan of even fastest NoSQL database.

[https://www.quora.com/Is-NoSQL-faster-than-SQL]

Answer (score 0):

> If you need the fastest database then Realm is the best choice:

- The ease of integration and the ease of use. Realm comes with great documentation and requires almost no effort to get started.
- Cross-Platform: Realm database files are cross-platform and can be shared among iOS and Android. Regardless if you work with Java, Objective-C, or Swift, you will use your high-level models.
- It’s a trusted product. The realm has proven itself as a reliable solution for banking and enterprise applications, healthcare providers and even top rated applications like Starbucks.

[image]

[[Reference]](https://expertise.jetruby.com/choosing-database-for-android-realm-vs-sqlite-51c90e83bafd) [[Resource](https://realm.io/products/realm-database/)]